# Runtime error '28': Out of stack space in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I try to a create a workbook for my requirement. The first sheet include a cell which type is 'Text' and it is for DATE value.

I add Workbook_Open method for set today date when open the workbook as shown below.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
     Sheet1.Range("F6") = Date
End Sub
```

And I also add Worksheet_Change method for sheet of that cell. That is for validation check as below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$F$6" Then

        'Getting insertion date.
        insertionDate = Sheet1.Range("F6")

        'If date field is not empty
        If insertionDate <> "" Then

            Call MsgBox("Insertion Date must be inserted.")

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

After that, I tested my code. When open the work book, I got the following error.

```
Run-time error '28': 
Out of stack space
```

When click 'Debug' button, the cursor shown at the first line of Worksheet_Change method.

I has tried everything what I thought. But nothing is going on. Help me. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it with this code. It is not satisfied for me but my problem is solved.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Address = "$F$6" Then

        'Getting insertion date.
        insertionDate = Sheet1.Range("F6")

        'If date field is not empty
        If insertionDate <> "" Then

            Call MsgBox("Insertion Date must be inserted.")

        End If

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: May be your code struck in recursive trigger event.

Comment: No, I think that is cause of "Multiple Sub". Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

`Msgbox` not need `Call` statement. Try to remove `Call` and test again.
And I have some reference from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/126090?wa=wsignin1.0. Its may be explain your error.

Answer (score 0):

Possible sources of error marked in the code

```
Option Explicit   ' Candidate

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$F$6" Then

        'Getting insertion date.
        Dim insertionDate as String   ' Candidate
        insertionDate = Sheet1.Range("F6").Text   ' Candidate

        'If date field is not empty
        If insertionDate <> "" Then
            MsgBox("Insertion Date must be inserted.")   ' Candidate
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Make sure you placed `Worksheet_Change` in the sheet module.

Comment: Actually, 'insertionDate' is declared as Public in other module. Thanks for your advice.